# Regex to find URL works on Regex101.com but not in C# code

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex pattern to match website:

`^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$`

If I test it (http://www.regex101.com) with the following values:

```
http://www.google.com 
google.com 
somesite.com
```

I get a match on all three values.

But this code doesn't work in C# (no matches):

```
var websiteRegex = new Regex(@"^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var stripped = stripped = phoneRegex
    .Replace("http://www.google.com www.google.com somesite.com", string.Empty);
```

Comment: How are you declaring `WEBSITE_PATTERN`?

Comment: private readonly string WEBSITE_PATTERN = @"^(?i)(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$";

Comment: Ahem, it cannot match the string `"http://www.google.com www.google.com somesite.com"` because you use the `^` and `$` anchors...

Comment: Thanks @elgonzo I wasn't sure what those did. I was just borrowing the pattern from someone else's example. Both your comment and Poul Bak's answer were correct!

Comment: The thing is your pattern matches the whole string that is a URL. If you tested against `"http://www.google.com\nwww.google.com\nsomesite.com"`, why do you think it will work the same against `"http://www.google.com www.google.com somesite.com"`?

Comment: Please update your **question** to show how `WEBSITE_PATTERN` is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple: regex101.com automatically apply the `'MultiLine'` option, which is necessary in your case.

Your code should be:

```
var websiteRegex = new Regex(WEBSITE_PATTERN, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.MultiLine);
```

Comment: The string in the question `"http://www.google.com www.google.com somesite.com"` doesn't contain line-feeds, but just simple spaces as url delimiters. I just checked the source text of the question. With regard to the string in the sample code in the question RegexOptions.MultiLine will not help...